# Python if-elif statements order

Tags: python, if-statement, random

I've encountered a problem that seems pretty much basic and simple and however I can't figure out a proper and elegant way how to solve it.

The situation is: there's a player who can move - let's say upward. While moving he can encounter some obstacles - let's say trees. And he can bypass them using a pretty simple algorithm like this one:

```
if   <the obstacle has a free tile on its RIGHT>:
  move_right() 
elif <the obstacle has a free tile on its LEFT>:
  move_left()
else:
  stop()
```

Well, it works perfectly, but there's a drawback: if the obstacle has free tiles both from its right and left so it can be bypassed from the both sides, the player always bypasses it from the right. It's pretty much explainable, but still not that cool.

The idea is to add some variety and randomize somehow the order in which the player checks the availability of tiles so if both are free he could move not necessarily to the right, but in random direction. And I must admit I cannot come up with an idea how to do it in a simple and beautiful way.

Basically, the solution should probably be something like this...

```
if random(0, 1) == 0:
  if   <the obstacle has a free tile on its RIGHT>:
    move_right() 
  elif <the obstacle has a free tile on its LEFT>:
    move_left()
  else:
    stop()
else:
  if   <the obstacle has a free tile on its LEFT>:
    move_left()
  elif <the obstacle has a free tile on its RIGHT>:
    move_right() 
  else:
    stop()
```

but I guess I don't need to explain why it doesn't seem the best one. =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put all available directions in a list, then use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) on that:

```
directions = []
if <the obstacle has a free tile on its RIGHT>:
    directions.append(move_right)
if <the obstacle has a free tile on its LEFT>:
    directions.append(move_left)

if not directions:
    stop()
else:
    random.choice(directions)()  # pick an available direction at random
```

The directions list will then have either 0, 1 or 2 function references in it; if it is empty, there were no options and you call `stop()`, otherwise you randomly pick from the list and call the picked function.

Because `random.choice()` raises `IndexError` if the input list is empty, you could make use tof that too:

```
try:
    # pick an available direction at random
    random.choice(directions)()
except IndexError:
    # no directions available
    stop()
```

Comment: Seems OK. But what if we make matters a bit more complicated?

Let's say there no methods like `move_right()` and `move_left()`, but there are just simple operations like `self.X += step` or `self.X -= step` instead.

Comment: @Romitas: you can add `lambda` functions instead; e.g. wrap the expression in an anonymous function: `directions.append(lambda: setattr(self, 'X', self.X + self.step))  # move right` (using `setattr()` as you cannot use statements in a `lambda`) or just create methods or local, nested functions for the movements anyway.