# Python if-else statement order

Tags: python, if-statement, random

My problem is similar to this one: [Python if-elif statements order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014314/python-if-elif-statements-order/27014368#27014368) but the answer is:

```
    #this was the answer given from the question I linked 
    directions = []
        if <the obstacle has a free tile on its RIGHT>:
              directions.append(move_right)
        if <the obstacle has a free tile on its LEFT>:
              directions.append(move_left)

    if not directions:
          stop()
    else:
         random.choice(directions)()
```

Now, my question is how do you input if statements into a list direction=[] ?
Is it a valid data type?
EDIT: I want to know how I would be able to apply the code above. Let's say there's object a in a maze and when it reaches an intersection this is the code i have:

```
   if (a is in intersection):
        a.forward()
   elif (forward().doesntexist):
        a.left()
   elif (left().doesntexist):
        a.right()
  ......
```

But this code would mean he'd always go forward first, then left, right, etc. I want its direction to be random that he may go right/forward/left first.

Comment: No. `if` statements are a syntactic construct. They're not data types or expressions. You can append a function however the implements the needed logic.

Comment: `directions=filter(lambda d:isTileFree(d),allDirections)`

Comment: `if` statements can't be written into lists, unless you mean list comprehensions, which is something different.  Please explain for given input, what is your expected output?

Comment: @Zipf, I updated my answer to give a crude "example" based on your recent question edit. If it doesn't work, please do as pylang mentioned in the previous comment and explain given inputs and your expected outputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import random

# example for a "free tile"
free_tile = (0,5)

def move_right():
    my_pos = free_tile
    return my_pos

def move_left():
    my_pos = free_tile
    return my_pos

def stop():
    print 'bye!'
    sys.exit(0)

directions = []

if free_tile == (0,5):
    print 'moving right'
    directions.append(move_right())

if free_tile == (0,6):
    print 'moving left'
    directions.append(move_left())

elif not directions:
    print 'no directions...exiting...'
    stop()
else:
    print random.choice(directions)

print 'current location', directions
```

Demo:

```
moving right
(0, 5)
current location [(0, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is some comment:

```
# init list
directions = []

# insert all possible directions into the list
# !!! NO else/elif here !!!
if ((forward possible)):
    directions.append(forward)
if ((left possible)):
    directions.append(left)
if ((right possible)):
    directions.append(right)

# now we have all possible directions
# stop if empty
if not directions:
      stop()
# otherwise randomly choose one
else:
     random.choice(directions)()
```

`if`-`else` statements are sequential. Although we would call that branch, but it is actually branching with sequential, just by skipping some statements with condition.